# How to combine several text files into one file?

Tags: python, file, glob

I want to combine several text files into one output files.
my original code is to download 100 text files then each time I filter the text from several words and the write it to the output file.

Here is part of my code that suppose to combine the new text with the output text. The result each time overwrite the output file, delete the previous content and add the new text.

```
import fileinput
import glob    
urls = ['f1.txt', 'f2.txt','f3.txt']

N =0;
print "read files"
for url in urls:
 read_files = glob.glob(urls[N])
 with open("result.txt", "wb") as outfile:
    for f in read_files:
        with open(f, "rb") as infile:
            outfile.write(infile.read())
 N+=1
```

and I tried this also

```
import fileinput
import glob
urls = ['f1.txt', 'f2.txt','f3.txt']

N =0;
print "read files"
for url in urls:
 file_list = glob.glob(urls[N])
 with open('result-1.txt', 'w') as file:
    input_lines = fileinput.input(file_list)
    file.writelines(input_lines)
 N+=1
```

Is there any suggestions?
I need to concatenate/combine approximately 100 text files into one .txt file In sequence manner. (Each time I read one file and add it to the result.txt)

Comment: you have to open the file with `a+` which is append mode, you keep opening it `wb` mode which will overwrite what you want every time

Comment: you have to open file with ```a+```.

Comment: It seems you already have the files.  Why do you need `glob`?

Comment: Open the output file once before the `for` loop that opens and reads each input file before writing to it, you wouldn't need to open it in `'a+'` append mode (regular `'w'` mode will be fine).

Comment: so what does glob do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are re-opening the output file on each loop iteration which will cause it to overwrite -- unless you explicitly open it in append mode.

The glob logic is also unnecessary when you already know the filename.

Try this instead:

```
with open("result.txt", "wb") as outfile:
    for url in urls:
        with open(url, "rb") as infile:
            outfile.write(infile.read())
```

Comment: The process of combining the txt files should done in a loop, this is why I can't open it before. The same loop is used in downloading and filtering the txt file. So in this case shall I use "a+" to be in safe side?